# Basis of External Direct Sum of infinitely many vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, direct-sum

In the book Basic Algebra by Arthur Knapp, he states that External Direct Sum for infinitely many vector spaces can be defined as below:

$\bigoplus_{a \in A} V_a$ is the set of tuples $\{v_a\}$ of the Cartesian product $\prod_{a \in A} V_a$ with *atmost finitely many* $v_a$ *equal to zero* and vector addition and scalar multiplication defined as usual. He remarks that the basis of $\bigoplus_{a \in A}$ is the union of basis of the constituent vector spaces.

Moreover, he further defines External Direct Product for infinitely many vector spaces in the similar manner *but excluding the highlighted condition.*

He then remarks that unlike the External Direct Sum, the External Direct Product doesn’t have a basis which can be represented via the collective basis of the vector spaces.

I am confused about why the highlighted condition is necessary for a basis to exist. Why can’t we just use the vectors $U_{a(i)} =(0,0,...,a(i),...)$ as the basis where $a(i)$ belongs to basis of $V_a$ and $a \in A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addition is a **binary** operation: it takes two vectors, and returns a vector. By induction, we can add *finitely many* vectors together. But we cannot add infinitely many vectors together.

So, for example, the vector $(1,1,1,1,\ldots)$ cannot be expressed as a linear combination of the vectors $\mathbf{e}_j$ (where $\mathbf{e}_j$ is an element of $\mathbb{R}^{\omega}$ in which the $i$th coordinate of $\mathbf{e}_j$ is $1$ if $i=j$ and $0$ otherwise), because **by definition**, a linear combination has only finitely many summands. So a linear combination of the $\mathbf{e}_i$ has only finitely many nonzero entries.

If you take the collection of vectors you propose, a linear combination of them, since by definition it can only involve finitely many vectors from your collection, will necessarily have zero entry in all but finitely many coordinates.

Comment: That makes sense. But the book says that atmost finitely many $v_a$ can be zero, which is the same as saying that that atleast infinitely many are non-zero.

Comment: @ValarmathiSenthilnathan: That’s a typo (or a mistranscription). It should be “at most finitely many are **nonzero**.”

Comment: In the second edition p.62 it says "with all but finitely many $v_\alpha$ equal to 0"